# Mikro-orm order by ST_Distance_Sphere using MySQL driver

Tags: mikro-orm

With MySQL, I am trying to order by `ST_Distance_Sphere` using `QueryBuilder`.

I have a entity:

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from "mikro-orm";

@Entity({ tableName: "studio" })
export default class StudioEntity {
    @PrimaryKey()
    public id!: number;

    @Property()
    public name!: string;

    @Property({ columnType: "point srid 4326" })
    public geometry!: object;
}
```

And I am trying:

```js
export default class StudioStore {
    private studioRepository: EntityRepository<StudioEntity>;

    public constructor(ormClient: OrmClient) {
        this.studioRepository = ormClient.em.getRepository(StudioEntity);
    }

    public async findPage(first: number): Promise<StudioEntity[]> {
        const query = this.studioRepository.createQueryBuilder().select("*");

        query.addSelect(
            "ST_Distance_Sphere(`e0`.`geometry`, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.612849 77.229883)', 4326)) as distance",
        );

        query.orderBy({ distance: "ASC" });

        return query.limit(first).getResult();
    }
}
```

But I get a ORM error:

> Trying to query by not existing property StudioEntity.distance

So, I try to add a property to the entity:

```js
    @Property({ persist: false })
    public distance?: number;
```

But now I get a MySQL error:

> Unknown column 'e0.distance' in 'order clause'

This is the generated SQL query:

```sql
[query] select `e0`.*, ST_Distance_Sphere(`e0`.`geometry`, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.612849 77.229883)', 4326)) as distance from `studio` as `e0` order by `e0`.`distance` asc limit 5 [took 4 ms]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fallback to knex, as QB currently supports only defined property fields in order by. You will also need to define that virtual `distance` property as you already did, so the value can be mapped to the entity.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/query-builder/#using-knexjs

```js
const query = this.studioRepository.createQueryBuilder().select("*");
query.addSelect("ST_Distance_Sphere(`e0`.`geometry`, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(28.612849 77.229883)', 4326)) as distance");
query.limit(first);
const knex = query.getKnexQuery();
knex.orderBy('distance', 'asc');
const res = await this.em.getConnection().execute(knex);
const entities = res.map(a => this.em.map(StudioEntity, a));
```

---

Not very nice I must say, totally forgot that it is possible to order by computed fields. Will try to address this in v4. I think it could even work as your second approach, as QB could simply check if the property is virtual (has `persist: false`), and then it would not prefix it.

edit: as of 3.6.6 the approach with `persist: false` should work out of box

Comment: If you want, I can open a issue at GitHub repo.

Comment: Yeah sure, otherwise I cannot promise I won't forget :]